# JPA 2: How many methods are allowed in one entity with @Prepersist annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, annotations

In JPA 2, how many methods can be declared with annotations like `@PrePersist` and in which order these methods are executed? Sometimes we also create different class for listener and apply this class on entity using `@EntityListener` annotation and we also declare methods in entity, so what is the order of execution of these methods?

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the order of invocation the JPA 2 spec section 3.5 states:

> If multiple entity listeners
>   are defined, the order in which they are invoked is determined by the order in which they are specified
>   in the EntityListeners annotation. The XML descriptor may be used as an alternative to
>   specify the invocation order of entity listeners or to override the order specified in metadata annotations.

And regarding wether using multiple methods for the same lifecycle event the JPA 2 Spec states in section 3.5:

> A single class must not have more than one lifecycle callback method for the same lifecycle event. The same method may be used for multiple callback events.

Answer (score 1):

A `@PrePersist` annotated method can be declared on:

- an entity class or any of its entity or mapped superclasses
- on default listeners declared globally on the XML descriptor
- on listeners referenced with the `@EntityListener` anotation in the entity class and any of his entity or mapped superclasses.

The order is defined in the 3.5.5 section of the JPA 2.2 spec (3.5.4 in the JPA 2.0 spec), and summarized it would be:

1. Global listeners in the order they are defined in the XML descriptor
2. `@EntityListeners` defined in the order they appear on the annotation on the entity classes. If there is an entity hieararchy listeners referenced on superclasses are executed before the listeners referenced in the subclasses.
3. Lifecycle method on the entity classes. If there is an entity hieararchy, lifecycle methods declared on superclasses are executed before methods declared on subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "Hibernate-flavoured" answer from the Hibernate docs for those using Hibernate's implementation of the JPA spec - [Chapter 6.2 Callbacks and Listener Inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html)

### Order of invocation

```
When an event is raised, the listeners are executed in this order:

- @EntityListeners for a given entity or superclass in the array order

- Entity listeners for the superclasses (highest first)

- Entity Listeners for the entity

- Callbacks of the superclasses (highest first)

- Callbacks of the entity
```

### Multiple methods

> The same callback method or entity listener method can be annotated
> with more than one callback annotation. **For a given entity, you cannot
> have two methods being annotated by the same callback annotation
> whether it is a callback method or an entity listener method.** A
> callback method is a no-arg method with no return type and any
> arbitrary name. An entity listener has the signature void
> (Object) where Object is of the actual entity type (note that
> Hibernate Entity Manager relaxed this constraint and allows Object of
> java.lang.Object type (**allowing sharing of listeners across several
> entities**.)